# How to get a function inside a script tag in react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, payment

I'm having difficulty using tag script in react js. I'm trying to use an online payments API. The first instruction to use the API is to use:

```html
 <script src="https://assets.pagseguro.com.br/checkout-sdk-js/rc/dist/browser/pagseguro.min.js"></script>
```

According to the API reference, the next step is:

- After including the JavaScript you must configure the function call **PagSeguro.encryptCard()** passing your public key in the publicKey parameter.

```js
var card = PagSeguro.encryptCard({
  publicKey: "MY_PUBLIC_KEY",
  holder: "First name Last name",
  number: "4242424242424242",
  expMonth: "12",
  expYear: "2030",
  securityCode: "123"
});

var encrypted = card.encryptedCard;
```

My problem is due to part **PagSeguro.encryptCard()**. PagSeguro is undefined. How to extract the **PagSeguro** and **encryptCard()** that is inside the script?

I'm using the code below:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

function Pay(){   

  const  [Infor, setInfor]=useState();

     useEffect(() => {
        
        const script = document.createElement('script');
      
        script.src = 'https://assets.pagseguro.com.br/checkout-sdk-js/rc/dist/browser/pagseguro.min.js';
        script.async = true;
         script.onload = (function(){ 
        setInfor(script);
       }) 
        console.log('script',script)
       
      const container = document.getElementById("mydiv"); 
      container.appendChild(script); 
       
      let card = script.PagSeguro.encryptCard({
        publicKey: "MINHA_CHAVE_PUBLICA",
        holder: "Nome Sobrenome",
        number: "4242424242424242",
        expMonth: "12",
        expYear: "2030",
        securityCode: "123"
      });
       console.log('card',card)             
      }, []);

  
return (
    <div id="mydiv">
     
<h1>Payment</h1>

</div>
);

}
export default Pay
```

This is the error message: **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'encryptCard')**

Comment: Where do you include that script in the DOM and where do you try and execute that code snippet?

Comment: When the `<script>` runs it exposes `PagSeguro` on the `window`. meaning you can directly reference it or also reference it with `window.PagSeguro`

Comment: I created a component called pay. And I use useEffect to try to use the script.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're including the external script *after* your code - as the API reference you quoted says:

> **After** including the JavaScript you must configure the function call...

You need your code to look something like the following:

```html
<script src="https://assets.pagseguro.com.br/checkout-sdk-js/rc/dist/browser/pagseguro.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Now, PagSeguro will have loaded
console.log(typeof PagSeguro);

// and you can proceed to use it

var card = PagSeguro.encryptCard({
  publicKey: "MY_PUBLIC_KEY",
  holder: "First name Last name",
  number: "4242424242424242",
  expMonth: "12",
  expYear: "2030",
  securityCode: "123"
});

var encrypted = card.encryptedCard;
</script>
```

If you don't want to block rendering while the script downloads, you could attach a `load` event listener to the script instead, and give it the `async` or `defer` attribute.

Comment: I did not understand. Where should I put this idea in React? In the component called Pay or html(root) ?

Comment: All you need to do is include the external script *first*, before the rest of your script, and then the `PagSeguro` object will be defined by the time you use it later. `<script src="https://assets.pagseguro.com.br/checkout-sdk-js/rc/dist/browser/pagseguro.min.js"></script>
<script>// rest of your script</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the script tag inside useEffect, you should call on public/index.html and call the SDK by window.PagSeguro. I succeed my implementation to encrypt card with PagSeguro. I'm from Brasil by the way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).